Imagemagick -remap option while keeping transparency
I have an image with transparency that I am trying to remap to a different color scheme in ImageMagick 7:
convert icon.png -remap palette.png out.png
However, this makes transparent pixels black (or the darkest color in the reference palette). None of the usual tricks like -colorspace sRGB or -transparent none work.
How can I remap an image while preserving transparency? I should note that this question is about 100% transparent pixels; there aren't pixels with like 20% opacity or anything.
